# Why am I getting "InvalidRequestError"?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement some foreign keys between tables and query using joins as per [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins) ORM tutorial:

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)

    def create_session(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()

class Bet(Base):

    __tablename__ = "bet"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "belgarath", "extend_existing": True})

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    match_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("belgarath.match_.id_"))

    match_ = relationship("Match", back_populates="belgarath.bet")

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = "match_"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "belgarath", "extend_existing": True})

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer)= Column(Integer)

dal = DataAccessLayer()
dal.create_session()

bets = dal.session.query(Bet)
bets.join(Match)
for bet in bets:
    print(bet.id_, bet.tournament_id = Column(Integer))
```

However I'm getting the following error on the `bets = dal.session.query(Bet)` line:

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidRequestError
Mapper 'mapped class Match->match_' has no property 'belgarath.bet'
```

Where am I going wrong? Do I need some kind of reciprocal relationship in `Match`?

Comment: Are you alreadly try to change ```back_populates``` to ```back_ref```.

Comment: Hi. I get the following error: ```TypeError: relationship() got an unexpected keyword argument 'back_ref'```

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaked.  ```backref``` not ```back_ref```